# An answer you gave is now incorrect/obsolete due to software updates.

Tags: discussion, answers

I answered this question.  [linux on baytrail tablets](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263654/can-linux-desktop-oss-work-on-baytrail-tablet-devices-that-ship-with-windows)

The answer I gave was correct at the time but it is now completely outdated as it mentions a kernel bug that has been fixed.

What should I do to update this?  Add another answer?  Edit the previous one? Should I delete the old answer?

Answer (score 40):

People might be using old kernel version, and for many reasons be unwilling or unable to update.

just update your answer with something like:

---

Kernel version 3.14.15.927 released on July 18, 2016 fixed this issue.

With older versions, [the existing answer]

Comment: @HuwEvans, also remember to accept your answer please.